# Press button on Internet Explorer website via Excel

Tags: internet-explorer

I've tried to solve my problem by myself but with no result: I need help.
With my code I can log to a website with usrn and psw, but to access the database I have to "click" the "Accetta" button and I don't know how to get it.
Here the website code:

```
<FORM  action="/xxx/HomeServlet" method="POST">
                    <input type="hidden" name="Ric" value="informativa">
                    <input type="hidden" name="informativa" value="true">
                    <input class="datiInput" type="submit" value="   Accetta   ">
```

How to proceed?
Thanks in advance.
V78

Answer (score 0):

All the Accetta button does is submitting the form. You can call the `submit` function on the form element by yourself

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("Submitting the form");
  document.forms[0].submit()
}, 1000);
```

```html
<FORM  action="/xxx/HomeServlet" method="POST">
                    <input type="hidden" name="Ric" value="informativa">
                    <input type="hidden" name="informativa" value="true">
                    <input class="datiInput" type="submit" value="   Accetta   ">
```

Or alternatively call the `click` function on the button input element

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("Clicking the button");
  document.getElementsByClassName("datiInput")[0].click();
}, 1000);
```

```html
<FORM  action="/xxx/HomeServlet" method="POST">
                    <input type="hidden" name="Ric" value="informativa">
                    <input type="hidden" name="informativa" value="true">
                    <input class="datiInput" type="submit" value="   Accetta   ">
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer, but I need the code for VBA as I'm doing it via Excel.

Comment: Solved! I just put a second readystate = 4 and an application.wait between the first instance (for login) and the second one (for "accetta" and go further to the database webapage).